# jQuery - Cannot hide siblings of a hidden parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following elements

```
<div id="newsfeeds">
    <div class="newsfeed">
       <img src="/path/to/image/1" />
       <span class="title">Text 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="newsfeed">
       <img src="/path/to/image/2" />
       <span class="title">Text 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="newsfeed">
       <img src="/path/to/image/3" />
       <span class="title">Text 3</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `.newsfeed` are all `hidden` except the very top one (so on the load, only the first one is visible).

When I click on a navigation, these newsfeed slide as controlled by the following jQuery:

```
var first = $('.newsfeed:first');
var next = first.next();
first.hide('slide',{duration: 1500}, function(){
    // Append as many needed
    $(this).appendTo('#newsfeeds');

    // THIS LINE DOES NOT WORK!
    first.find('.title').hide();

});
next.show('slide',{direction : 'right' , duration: 1500});

setInterval(function(){
    next.find('.title').fadeIn(500);
},1500 + 100);
```

On the first load, the first `.newsfeed` is visible, and the `.title` for it is also loaded. Once I click "next", I want the slide thing to hide the first `newsfeed` and show the next (this works just fine). At this point, after the sliding effect, the `.title` of the second `newsfeed` also fades in (this works also).

However, I also want the `.title` of the first div to now `hide()` so that on when I come to it again, the `.title` shows after the `newsfeed` slides in. This doesn't happen (i.e., once you slide through the banner once, the title always remains). What am I doing wrong? I am hiding the div! Then why is not being hidden?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remember - for .hide() you need *jQuery UI effects*, or it will fail as the method for Object does not exist (slide), so the construct of hide(...) will fail.
2. Reuse the DOM elements that you already have, otherwise your script will append  f*** a lot to the DOM.

*Maybe this will work for you:*
has some stuff, fade in and out, set times, goes through elements, then starts from beginning.

html:

```
<div id="newsfeeds">
<div class="newsfeed">
   <img src="http://www.iconshock.com/img_jpg/SHINE7/communications/jpg/256/phone_icon.jpg" />
   <span class="title">Text 1</span>
</div>
<div class="newsfeed" style="display:none;">
   <img src="http://www.iconshock.com/img_jpg/REALVISTA/mobile/jpg/256/android_platform_icon.jpg" />
   <span class="title" style="display:none;">Text 2</span>
</div>
<div class="newsfeed" style="display:none;">
   <img src="http://www.iconshock.com/img_jpg/LUMINA/accounting/jpg/256/plane_icon.jpg" />
   <span class="title" style="display:none;">Text 3</span>
</div>
```

Some JavaScript:

```
var first = $('#newsfeeds .newsfeed:first-child'),
    current = first;
    next = first.next(),
    hideTime = 2000,
    fadeTime = 500;

function showHideNext() {
    console.log('next: ' + next.find('.title').html());
    console.log('current: ' + current.find('.title').html());
    current.hide('slide', {}, hideTime, function() {
        current.find('.title').css('display', 'none');
        next.show('slide', {}, fadeTime, function() {
                next.find('.title').show(fadeTime);
            });
        });
    current = next;
    next = next.next().length ? next.next() : first;
}

setInterval(function(){
    showHideNext();
}, hideTime + fadeTime + 100);
```

[a little jsFiddling lunch time](http://jsfiddle.net/BepG4/1/)

Have fun.